# Randomly fill columns of a matrix using a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to fill the below matrix, by column, with a random selection of values contained in the variable `hub`.

```
hub <- c(1) # there can be only one '1' per column.
for(i in 1:(49)){
  no <- 0
  hub <- c(hub,no)
}

matriz_hubs <- matrix(data = sample(hub),nrow = 50,ncol = hub_total,byrow = FALSE)
```

Although this code works, it places all the '1' values on the same row. Is there a way it could randomly select the values for each column?

Comment: what's `hub_total` ?

Comment: Oups sorry I forgot that one, it contains the required number of hubs for each problem, in this case 5.
I need to fill the matrix with 1 if a node becomes a hub or a 0 if it doesn't, and one of the requirements is that there is only one server per column.

Comment: The first part of your code, including the `for` loop, is basically the same as `hub <- c(1, rep(0, 49))`, only absurdly awkward. So basically you want to form random columns of 50 elements, with 49 `0` and one `1`?

Comment: I wasn't happy with the for loop either but I wasn't too sure on how to modify it, thanks for the alternative code!. Yes, I need to fill a random number of columns (which number is contained in the variable hub_total) and fill them with 49 `0` and one `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- do.call("cbind", lapply(1:5, function(x) sample(c(1, rep(0, 49)), 50)))

> mat
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0
[13,]    0    0    0    0    0
[14,]    0    0    0    0    0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    0
[16,]    0    0    1    0    0
[17,]    0    0    0    0    0
[18,]    0    0    0    0    0
[19,]    0    0    0    0    0
[20,]    0    0    0    0    0
[21,]    0    0    0    0    0
[22,]    0    0    0    0    0
[23,]    0    0    0    0    0
[24,]    0    0    0    0    0
[25,]    0    0    0    0    0
[26,]    0    0    0    0    0
[27,]    1    0    0    0    0
[28,]    0    0    0    0    0
[29,]    0    0    0    0    0
[30,]    0    0    0    0    0
[31,]    0    0    0    0    0
[32,]    0    0    0    0    0
[33,]    0    0    0    0    0
[34,]    0    0    0    0    0
[35,]    0    0    0    0    0
[36,]    0    0    0    0    0
[37,]    0    0    0    0    0
[38,]    0    0    0    0    0
[39,]    0    0    0    0    0
[40,]    0    0    0    0    0
[41,]    0    0    0    0    0
[42,]    0    1    0    0    0
[43,]    0    0    0    1    0
[44,]    0    0    0    0    1
[45,]    0    0    0    0    0
[46,]    0    0    0    0    0
[47,]    0    0    0    0    0
[48,]    0    0    0    0    0
[49,]    0    0    0    0    0
[50,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

You can choose more or less columns by changing the `5` in `1:5` within `lapply` to the value you want.

You could even write a function:

```
BUILDMAT <- function(nrow, ncol){
  mat <- do.call("cbind", lapply(1:ncol, function(x) sample(c(1, rep(0, nrow-1)), nrow)))
  return(mat)
}
```

Now just call it like this:

```
test <- BUILDMAT(10, 5)

> test
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    1    1    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    1    1    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
```